# Implementing usage limits for resources (vm/storage) by internal projects

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Our organization contains many different projects, each containing users. I'd like to be able to set a cap which prevents each project from exceeding their respective monetary budget for vms or storage resources.

So far I see that I can create a budget with a specific scope for resource groups, and assign a dollar value.

I'm wondering if in order to manage our projects like this they each need their own subscription to be used as scope?

Also, do I understand correctly that resource groups will allow me to select storage and compute resources so these do not exceed the set dollar limit?  Is there a mechanism for setting quotas in vm counts or storage amount?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Policy for better control of the number / SKU:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview#policy-definition